# sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java

I am using MACBook Pro and i installed java version "Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk". When i try to build the the project i am getting below error and after i download the certificates and import also same error i am facing.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'bdsi.commerce.code'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 'classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:2.4.7.
> Required by:
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
> > Could not resolve com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:2.4.7.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/yahoo/platform/yui/yuicompressor/2.4.7/yuicompressor-2.4.7.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/yahoo/platform/yui/yuicompressor/2.4.7/yuicompressor-2.4.7.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.0.0.
> Required by:
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
> > Could not resolve org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.0.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/gpars/gpars/1.0.0/gpars-1.0.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/gpars/gpars/1.0.0/gpars-1.0.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

If any one have idea on this please help me. Thank you in advannce.

I download the certificates and import also same error i am facing.

Comment: If you're using Java 8 update 191, you should really update to a newer version. The latest Java 8 is Java 8 update 352. Chances are that update solves your problem (e.g. because of newer CA root certificates).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Intellij Idea, you can add VM options on
Maven.Importing and Maven.Runner configs

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for responding.

Actually i am using Eclipse and i am building project in Mac terminal.
Command: ./gradlew cA dA